# Removing a column from angular mat-table

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have this angular mat-table and a button to add or remove a column the issue I have is that only on remove I get this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnDef' of undefined,

the parent component just talks to an api and returns data to the input variables.

stepped through and can't find any data that is undefined so it must be some lifecycle thing I don't understand yet. Any ideas appreciated.

```
import { Component, Inject, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import paginationDefaults from '../../constants/pagination.config';
import { ConfigureQueryComponent } from '../configure-query/configure-query.component';
import { ColumnBuilder } from './column-builder';
import { ColumnModel } from 'src/app/models/table-definition.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss']
})

export class DataTableComponent implements OnDestroy, OnChanges {
  @Output() pageEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() sortEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input() data: any[] = [];
  @Input() metaData: any = {};
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() selectable: boolean;
  @Input() allColumns: any[] = [];
  @Input() availableAggregates: string[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  initialized = false;
  loading = true;
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  pageProps = paginationDefaults;
  paginator: MatPaginator;

  _allColumns: any[] = [];

  availableColumns: any[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  factory = {
    sortActive: '',
    sortDirection: 'asc',
    columns: []
  };

  /**
   * @param route used to build the params
   * @param dataService the service for the api endpoints
   * @param router used to navigate to individual detail views (future implementation)
   * @param dialog Material Dialog to open the Configure Columns component
   * @param columnBuilder contains the logic to build and change the table columns
   */
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    @Inject(ColumnBuilder) public columnBuilder: ColumnBuilder
  ) {}

  /**
   * @description - subscribes to the dataService method to call updateData with the api result when it's returned.
   *  also subscribes to the subject in the columnBuilder class for when the columns are updated.
   *  put both subscriptions into an array to make managing easier.
   */
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.warn('ngOnChanges');

    if (!this.initialized && this.allColumns.length > 0 && this.availableAggregates.length > 0) {
      this._allColumns = this.allColumns;
      this.initialized = true;
      this.manageSubscriptions();
    }

    if (this.initialized && this.data) {
      this.updateData();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @description unsubscribes to all the subscriptions on route change
   */
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

  /**
   * @description - manages two subscriptions, one for listening to when data is returned and the one for listening to the column
   *  builder class for when the displayed columns, all columns, and factory columns have been updated. Pushes these to a subscriptions
   *  array to unsubscribe to all them easier when the route is changed.
   */
  manageSubscriptions() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());

    const columnBuilderSubscription = this.columnBuilder.columnsUpdatedSubject.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.displayedColumns = data.displayedColumns;
      this._allColumns = data.availableColumns;
      this.factory.columns = data.factoryColumns;


      console.warn('columnBuilderSubscription', this.displayedColumns, this.factory.columns);

      this.buildTable();
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(columnBuilderSubscription);
  }

  /**
   * @description updates the data and builds columns from the service result.
   * @param res an object of the service call results, including the query params.
   */
  updateData(): void {
      this.pageProps.currentPage = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.page;

      if (this.metaData.count) {
        this.pageProps.totalRecords = this.metaData.count;
      }

      this.buildColumns();
  }

  /**
   * @description calls the setColumns function in the columnBuilder class and passes through the data and type.
   */
  buildColumns(): void {
    /**
     * @todo use this function to trigger building the table and decprecate the behavioourSubject description
     */
    this.columnBuilder.setColumns(this.data, this.type, this._allColumns);
  }

  /**
   * @description shortens the column header text to format nicely in the table
   */
  truncateText(input: string): string {
    if (input.length > 20) {
      return input.substring(0, 20) + '...';
    } else {
      return input;
    }
  }

  public setLoadingState(val: boolean) {
    this.loading = val;
  }

  /**
   * @description - opens the config query pop up and passes through all columns and the available aggregates. On close it
   *  builds the columns again.
   */
  openConfig() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfigureQueryComponent, {
      id: 'QueryConfigDialog',
      width: '95%',
      data: {
        context: this.type,
        columns: this._allColumns,
        aggregates: this.availableAggregates
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.availableColumns = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('COL_CONFIG')) || false;
      this.buildColumns();
    });
  }

  /**
   * @description creates a new dataSource for the table
   */
  buildTable(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.data);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  /**
   * @description changes the route to navigate to the individual detail page
   * @param index row data uuid number
   */
  public getDetails(index: number): void {
    this.router.navigate([this.data[index].url]);
  }

  /**
   * @description handles the page event on pagination change
   * @param e material pagination details
   */
  public handlePage = (e: any) => {
    this.loading = true;

    this.pageEvent.emit({
      page: e.pageIndex,
      limit: e.pageSize
    });
  }

  public handleSortBy(e: any): void {
    this.loading = true;

    this.sortEvent.emit({
      sort: e.active,
      direction: e.direction,
      page: 0
    });

    this.factory.sortActive = e.active,
    this.factory.sortDirection = e.direction;
  }

  /**
   * @description if no data is returned from the dataService, return true.
   */
  showNoResults(): boolean {
    if (this.data === undefined) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  setDefaultColumns(columnData: ColumnModel[]) {
    const defaultColumnAmount = 8;
    const columns = this.filterOnlyStatic(columnData).splice(0, defaultColumnAmount);
    columns.forEach((c) => {
      c.show = true;
      c.index = columns.indexOf(c);
    });
    return columns;
  }

  filterOnlyStatic(columns: ColumnModel[]) {
    return columns.filter((col) => col.columnType === 'STATIC' && !col.columnDef.includes('DEVICE'));
  }
}
```

Comment: It can't be regarding a life cycle hook because columnDef is mentioned in this code only once. Therefore, if there was a problem with the column because of some life cycle, the col.ColumnType in your filterOnlyStatic would return an undefined before the columnDef.  Some data is missing here. try to reverse debug the chain of operations and understand what is happening with columnDef

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on https://stackblitz.com/ and paste the link here? It would allow us to help you.

Comment: it would take a super long time to get this running in a stackblitz, but if time goes on too much I may have to.